# Make child div stretch across width of page

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 960px">
   <div id="help_panel" style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
     Content goes here.
   </div> 
</div>
```

If I want the help_panel div to stretch across the width of the page/broswer, even if the width of the page/browser is wider than 960px (which is the width set for the container div), is it possible to do it with the above structure?  I want to get the help panel div to expand beyond the width limits set in the container div if the page is wider than 960px.

I am curious if this can be accomplished with the above structure.  Or will I have to put the help_panel div outside of the container div to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes it can be done. You need to use

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/bJbgJ/3/

Comment: This works, but does not take into account any content after the full width element (see @esel's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5590260/863846)). Is it possible to do something like this but still affect the rest of the content?

Comment: This does not work if the child that you're setting has a parent that is set to position:relative that is not the full width of the page.

Comment: Why is this not working on textarea? Whats the difference between textarea (display: block) and div? It is not acting the same way.

Comment: @LucyBain - i had the same problem. you can use jQuery on page load to add a bottom margin to the container, it will then show all of the child div content.

 var cntmarg = $( "#help-panel" ).height();
    $("#container").css('margin-bottom', cntmarg);

Answer (score 40):

With current browsers (this question is dating a bit now), you can use the much simpler `vw` (viewport width) unit:

```
#help_panel {
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
  width: 100vw;
}
```

(usage data: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

From my tests, this should not break your flow while being easy to use.

Comment: This is good. Even better without using calc: https://coderwall.com/p/hkgamw/creating-full-width-100-container-inside-fixed-width-container

Comment: I love it! Maybe good to add that it only works if the containing parent is in the centered on the page (it had me scratching my head for a while how it works). Basically the `margin-left: 50%` centers the left-margin in the parent container (which is the center of the page if the parent container is centered), then `-50vw` moves it left half a page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, set the `position: relative` for the container and `position: absolute` for the help_panel

Comment: not quite... container needs to have `position:static`, which it does by default.  If you set it to `relative`, the nested div will stretch to the parent width even with `position:absolute` set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `100vw` (viewport width). `100vw` means 100% of the viewport. `vw` is [supported by all major browsers, including IE9+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

```
<div id="container" style="width: 960px">
   <div id="help_panel" style="width: 100vw; margin: 0 auto;">
     Content goes here.
   </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can pull it out of the flow by setting `position:absolute` on it, but you'll have different display issues to deal with.  Or you can explicitly set the width to > 960.

Answer (score -1):

You *could* do it with jQuery...

```
$("#help_panel").width($(window).width());
```

Otherwise, as far as css goes, I'm fairly sure you would have to sit the `help_panel` div on the outside of `container` using `position:absolute` styling: http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/2318/give-child-div-width%3A100-of-page-width-inside-parent./p1

Answer (score -1):

You could take it out of the flow with position:absolute.  But the helper_panel will oberlap with other stuff. (I added orders, to see the divs)

```
<div id="container" style="width: 960px; border:1px solid #f00;">
    Text before<br>
   <div id="help_panel" style="width: 100%; position:absolute; margin: 0 auto; border:1px solid #0f0;">
     Content goes here.
   </div> 
   This is behind the help_penal
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set the width to 100vw like this:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100vw">
 <div id="help_panel" style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
  Content goes here.
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: It pushes content out right, but does not overlap the parent on the left, for me at any rate

Answer (score -1):

Since `position: absolute;` and viewport width were no options in my special case, there is another quick solution to solve the problem. The only condition is, that overflow in x-direction is not necessary for your website.

You can define negative margins for your element:

```
#help_panel {
    margin-left: -9999px;
    margin-right: -9999px;
}
```

But since we get overflow doing this, we have to avoid overflow in x-direction globally e.g. for body:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

You can set `padding` to choose the size of your content.

**Note** that this solution does not bring 100% width for content, but it is helpful in cases where you need e.g. a background color which has full width with a content still depending on container.

Comment: It might work for colour alone, but if I put content inside it, it gets pushed off the screen to the left

Answer (score -1):

...............In HTML Format

```
<div id="a">Full Width</div>
```

...............In CSS Format

```
#a { background-color: green;width: 100%;height: 80px;border: 1px solid;margin: 0 auto;} 

    body { padding: 0;margin: 0}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this: it will use all of the screen width:

```
min-width: 100vw;
```

Answer (score -2):

I know this post is old, in case someone stumbles upon it in 2019, this would work try it.

```
//html
<div id="container">
<div id="help_panel">
<div class="help_panel_extra_if_you_want"> //then if you want to add some height and width if you want, do this.

</div>
</div>
</div>

//css
#container{
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
z-index: 100;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-box-pack: start;
-webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
-ms-flex-pack: start;
justify-content: flex-start;    
position: relative;
height:650px;
margin-top:55px;
margin-bottom:-20px;
}

#help_panel {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
padding-right: 24px;
padding-left: 18px;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;

.help_panel_extra_if_you_want{
height:650px;
position: relative;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row;
-webkit-box-pack: justify;
-webkit-justify-content: space-between;
-ms-flex-pack: justify;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
display: flex;
width: 95%;
max-width: 1200px;
}
```

SHOULD GIVE YOU SOMETHING LIKE THIS
[image: This is how it would look, adjust the width and margin and padding to achieve what you want]

Comment: This is not answer this question at all.

Answer (score -3):

You can do:

```
margin-left: -50%;
margin-right: -50%;
```

Comment: This did nothing for me. Didn't move the div, didn't resize it.