# Placing footer at bottom AND expand it to full screen WITHOUT re-aligning HTML

Tags: html, css, footer, nopcommerce

I have a footer which expands to full width of screen and my content area is 960px wide. I want the footer to always be at bottom of the page. Now the problem is that I cannot place footer's html at the end since I am following the NopCommerce framework and I must place all of my content inside the two main wrapper divs which are 960px & 930px wide.

I know that I can make my footer expand beyond the container div as mentioned at [Extend child div beyond container div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849717/extend-child-div-beyond-container-div). But I want to know whether this can be achieved without using JS? Setting footer to position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; left:0 does not work as the footer gets stuck if I scroll down on page. I also cannot use position:fixed and bottom:0 as it will make other content scroll below it, which is not what I want.

HTML:

```
<div class="master-wrapper-page">
<div class="master-wrapper-content">
<footer></footer>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.master-wrapper-page {
  margin: 2px auto 0;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5em 2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  width: 960px;
}

.master-wrapper-content {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px 15px 0;
  padding: 15px 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 930px;
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  clear: both;
  height: 248px;
  z-index: 90000;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle in case it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/6rLco5kq/
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look here. Do you mean that ?

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  clear: both;
  height: 248px;
  z-index: 90000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6rLco5kq/1/

Comment: Directly from the question body: *...it will make other content scroll below it, which is not what I want.*

Answer (score 0):

I was messing around with your jsfiddle and you could add

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: xx;
```

To your `footer`, and then add this to your `master-wrapper-content` to keep your content from overflowing onto your footer.

```
margin-bottom: 248px;
```

Comment: Adding position fixed and bottom:0 does not work as it makes the footer stick at bottom of screen(in case of position:fixed) or in the middle (in case of position:absolute) but it does not scroll down with rest of the page. You may see it for yourself as I have updated my fiddle to include content above footer so that scrolling behavior can also be checked.