# Stretch an individual child DIV beyond parent to another ancestor

Tags: css

There are some [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849717/extend-child-div-beyond-container-div) on stretching a child DIV but I can't make any major `position` `static/relative` changes and would prefer to keep all changes to a minimum. In the below snippet, I need to stretch the blue **Header** DIV so that extends all the way to the **Main** DIV, while the form elements below continue to obey the margins/padding as specified. Is there a quick solution?

If I add an `overflow: visible;` and enlarge the `width` that doesn't help me, it only overflows the right and not the left.

```css
.main {
   background-color: lightgray;
}

.gridcontainer {
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.header { /* Needs to be stretched all the way to "main" without major changes */
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
   <div class="main">
      <div class="gridcontainer">
         <div>
             <header class="header">
                 <h1>Main Header</h1>
                 <h3>Subheader</h3>
             </header>
             
             <form>
                Field1: <input type="text" /><br/>
                Field2: <input type="text" /><br/>
             </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for `<br>` and all self-closing HTML tags.

Comment: is it only about the coloration? if so, see this: https://css-tip.com/overflowing-background/

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative margin `-4rem` to compensate for the padding and margin of 2rem each.

```css
.main {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.gridcontainer {
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.header {
  /* Needs to be stretched all the way to "main" without major changes */
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: red;
  margin-left: -4rem;
  margin-right: -4rem;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="gridcontainer">
      <div>
        <header class="header">
          <h1>Main Header</h1>
          <h3>Subheader</h3>
        </header>

        <form>
          Field1: <input type="text" /><br/> Field2: <input type="text" /><br/>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need a different solution. In the actual code, the margins are `auto`, and the negative value doesn't work for `margin-right`. I only showed a simpler example.

Comment: what are the constraints? are you allowed to change the html markup or only the css? providing a [mre] could help