# Full width child div within container parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to span a child div the full width of the page from within a fixed width container parent div. I've found a few posts on how to do this but nothing seems to work for me. [This overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590214/make-child-div-stretch-across-width-of-page) in particular seems to make it work with position: absolute; and left:0; right: 0; however, my div disappears when i use absolute positioning. The div does span the full width when using position: fixed; but I dont want fixed positioning :(

I've tried numerous things now and I'm pulling my hair out with this seemingly easy task. Please see my link below where I am using fixed position on my lightgray div for the sake of the example - if you change to absolute position you will see the div disappears.

Here is my test link - http://www.daybreakutah.com/test-3/

All and any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be in the same div? Seems like you'd save yourself a lot of trouble by taking it out of the div, applying the CSS you'd like to it and repositioning it.

Comment: @LanceLafontaine is right, it would be a lot easier if the div could be taken out of it's parent but this may not be an option. What is the reason for having the grey div 100%; simply for a background color or do you plan to have a full width image?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the responses. To answer your questions, yes, the design agency sent over a new landing page design that has a background "texture" image that spans the full width of the page. Also, as this is a Wordpress site, I believe it has to be in the same (".post-data") div unless I'm overthinking this. Again, thanks for your help so far! This one is peculiar huh?

Comment: Which div are you trying to make the full width of the page? I can't tell.

Comment: The light gray div. It is a child of the ".post-data" div. Which actually has relative positioning (so absolute position on my gray div should work in theory).

Comment: It only disappears because you have the parent div set to `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're after - but try [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/3yt905g9/1/)

Comment: Ok, i commented out overflow: hidden and can now see the grey div when absolute positioned but it does not span full width. Still inspecting, thanks all. any help is appreciated!

Comment: Update: I removed position:relative on a few parent div's and was able to span my div full width, however now it will not grow in height. Still troubleshooting. Please let me know of any ideas, thanks again!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: This is a very peculiar issue on a Wordpress site that I was not able to replicate with code outside of my Wordpress site. That was the reason that I linked to my site after providing a detailed description to my problem.